# AS3: Scale movieclip at another movieclips position?

Tags: actionscript-3, zooming, scale, movieclip

I'm trying to scale a base image based on a movieclip's x and y position? The base image image is also a MC.

```
infoIconCompFit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, zoomInCompFit);
infoIconCompFit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, zoomOutCompFit);

function zoomInCompFit(event:MouseEvent):void {
   TweenLite.to(baseImage, 1, {scaleX:2, scaleY:2});
}

function zoomOutCompFit(event:MouseEvent):void {
   TweenLite.to(baseImage, 1, {scaleX:1, scaleY:1});
}
```

What I mean is; is it possible to scale a movieclip at another movieclip's x and y position on the stage? Like I want the base movieclip to scale (zoom in) at the position of another movieclip on Mouse ROLL_OVER then zoom out on Mouse ROLL_OUT.

I get it to where it zooms in and out on the handlers, but how do I get it to zoom at that position relative to the other MC?

(Before) http://www.marketingfanatics.co.za/images/exampleNormal.jpg
(After) http://www.marketingfanatics.co.za/images/exampleZoomedl.jpg

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you include an image that depicts the before and after of what you expect to happen ?

Comment: @prototypical Please see the images above to see what I mean.

Comment: @prototypical i need the main image to scale at the blue information icon's x and y position. I don't even know if that's possible, but I keep having this feeling that it shouldn't be this complicated. Like I'm missing something.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But you need to write some code and have in mind where is transformation pivot of those Objects.

```
/**
         * Calculate position and dimensions of image to zoom.
         * @param   img - image to animate, need to have transformation pivot in top left corner!
         * @param   point - point to zoom in (or null if zoom out) that will be new center of image
         * @param   scale - scale in zoom in
         * @param   viewWidth - container width
         * @param   viewHeight - container height
         * @return  object for tween engine with parameters to animate
         */
        private function centerOn(img:DisplayObject, point:Point=null, scale:Number=2, viewWidth:Number=300, viewHeight:Number=200):Object
        {
            var r:Object;
            var mm:Matrix = img.transform.matrix;
            img.transform.matrix = new Matrix();

            if (point == null) { // oryginal size
                r = { x: 0, y: 0, width: img.width, height: img.height };
            }else { // zoom
                img.scaleX = img.scaleY = scale;
                point.x *= scale;
                point.y *= scale;
                img.x = -point.x + viewWidth / 2;
                img.y = -point.y + viewHeight / 2;
                r = { x: img.x, y: img.y, width: img.width, height: img.height };
            }
            img.transform.matrix = mm;
            return r;
        }
```

Use example:

```
TweenLite.to(baseImage, 1, centerOn(baseIMG, new Point(100, 150))); //zoom in
TweenLite.to(baseImage, 1, centerOn(baseIMG)); //zoom out
centerOn(img, new Point(200, 135), 4, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); // to fit stage size
```

Remember that your Display Object is not masked and sometimes (zoom near borders) you will see scene under it!

PS. Code tested.